# Error ID0006 while configuring AD FS Authentication in Exchange 2013

Tags: exchange, adfs

I have a fresh installation of Exchange 2013 (with SP1) hosted on a Windows Server 2012R2 box. I want to configure it for ADFS authentication. I ran the powershell commands to set the ADFS authentication to true.

```
Get-EcpVirtualDirectory| Set-EcpVirtualDirectory -AdfsAuthentication $true -BasicAuthentication $false -DigestAuthentication $false -FormsAuthentication $false -WindowsAuthentication $false
Get-OwaVirtualDirectory | Set-OwaVirtualDirectory -AdfsAuthentication $true -BasicAuthentication $false -DigestAuthentication $false -FormsAuthentication $false -WindowsAuthentication $false
```

> After restarting IIS, I get the following error:
>
> Server Error in '/ecp' Application. ID0006: The input string parameter
>   is either null or empty. Parameter name: value

I tried the following to resolve but to not effect:

a) Added the AD FS Token Signing Certificate to the Trusted Root Certification Authorities Store on the Exchange Server.
b) Added internal and external URL on the Virtual Directories.

Any thoughts on the cause and the resolution?

Answer (score 0):

What are you using for the ADFS certificate, issued by the Enterprise CA or public CA?

You should import the root certificate of the ADFS certificate chain to the “Trusted Root Certification Authorities Store” on the Exchange Servers.

What is your Exchange CU? Try the latest CU.

In another way, try to re-configurate the ADFS by the following article:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients/outlook-on-the-web/ad-fs-claims-based-auth?view=exchserver-2019

Comment: It is a Self Signed Certificate. It is in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities on the Exchange Server.

Comment: Please check the certificate requirement with the above link. You need two certificates for ADFS, one is issued by a CA, and one is self-signed token-signing certificate.

Comment: I created a new certificate for Exchange from within the ECP but the old one is always getting picked up. Any particular reason why this issue occurs only after turning on AD FS authentication?